Alternative to .execution.shots (Qiskit)
I've been trying to learn quantum computing from the IBM courses, but when trying to run this code, it doesn't seem to work, always seeming to get stuck on execution.shots
Is there anything I can do about this?
#Estimated required time: <20 min. Benchmarked at 17 min, 40 s on ibm_osaka, on 5-29-24

 x0 = np.ones(8)

 with Session(backend=backend) as session:
      session_options = Options()
      session_options.execution.shots = 4096
      session_options.resilience_level = 1

      estimator = Estimator(session=session)
      sampler = Sampler(session = session)
      estimator.options.default_shots = 10_000

      result = minimize(cost_func_vqe, x0, args=(isa_ansatz, isa_observable, estimator), method="COBYLA")

session.close()

print(result)

It seems to throw out this error
{
"name": "AttributeError",
"message": "'OptionsV2' object has no attribute 'execution'",
"stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
Cell In[9], line 7
      5 with Session(backend=backend) as session:
      6     session_options = Options()
----> 7     session_options.execution.shots = 4096
      8     session_options.resilience_level = 1
     10     estimator = Estimator(session=session)

AttributeError: 'OptionsV2' object has no attribute 'execution'"
}


According to Qiskit Runtime V2 primitives migration guide,

Sampler V2 PUB (primitive unified Bloc) format is (<circuit>, <parameter values>, <shots>)
Sampler V2 has the shots argument in its run() method.

So, you can sample all your circuits the same number of shots,
sampler.run([circuit1, circuit2], shots=1024)

Or, sample each circuit a different number of shots,
sampler.run([
  (circuit1, None, 512),
  (circuit2, None, 1024),
])

